# The Guristas 5/10 DED complex " Guristas Hallucinogen Supply Waypoint"

Tags: eve-online

I just did the Guristas 5/10 DED complex with my Ishtar, and while I managed in the end I found the last room to be very problematic. I had to warp out twice and lost a lot of Heavy Drones due to that.

I'm using a Heavy Drone Ishtar with the following fit:

```
[Ishtar]

Beta Reactor Control: Shield Power Relay I
Damage Control II
Drone Damage Amplifier II
Drone Damage Amplifier II
Drone Damage Amplifier II

10MN Afterburner II
Large Shield Extender II
Large Shield Extender II
Adaptive Invulnerability Field II
Drone Navigation Computer I

Drone Link Augmentor II
Small 'Solace' Remote Armor Repairer
Small 'Solace' Remote Armor Repairer
[Empty High slot]

Medium Core Defense Field Purger II
Medium Core Defense Field Purger II


Wasp II x5
Vespa EC-600 x5
Ogre II x5
```

My skills are pretty good, the ship skill and the important drone damage skills at 5. The Ship does roughly 700 dps with Wasps, and has 440 dps tank against Guristas.

I tried to kill the Stasis Towers first, but that took too long and I took too much damage in that time. What tactic can work in that last room? Blitzing doesn't seem an option as I can't move fast enough with the Stasis Towers to loot the Overseer.

I found the following tip in the EVE Wiki:

> Tip from ShadowNeo29: the last pocket is pretty easy, kill only the Gurista Distributor, bookmark the wreck and warp out. Come back 2 min after for loot/salvage.

I tried to bookmark the room and warp back, but that didn't work and I ended up at the first acceleration gate again. What exactly is this tip trying to achieve, how does it work and what could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem you are having is that the stasis webifiers are reducing your speed too much allowing the Guristas' missiles to do full damage, in this instance that is around 1700 dps. This is a similar problem I have when running The Maze 10/10 DED complex. Instead of speed tanking, you can go full passive shield regen:

```
[Ishtar]

Beta Reactor Control: Shield Power Relay I
Beta Reactor Control: Shield Power Relay I
Beta Reactor Control: Shield Power Relay I
Drone Damage Amplifier II
Drone Damage Amplifier II

Large Shield Extender II
Large Shield Extender II
Large Shield Extender II
Pith A-Type Thermic Dissipation Field
Pith A-Type Kinetic Deflection Field

Drone Link Augmentor II
Drone Link Augmentor II
[Empty High slot]

Medium Core Defense Field Purger II
Medium Core Defense Field Purger II


Wasp II x5
Vespa EC-600 x5
Ogre II x5
```

The above fit, with all skills 5 and no boosts or implants will tank 1750 Guristas DPS and does 650 dps with Wasp IIs. If your skills are a bit low, you can drop a Drone Damage Amplifier and put on another Shield Power Relay (at max skills that is a 2200 dps tank) or you can consider using the following implants:

- Zainou 'Gnome' Shield Management SM-703
- Zainou 'Gnome' Shield Operation SP-906

If you don't want to use the deadspace hardeners, you can swap them to T2 but you will need to replace a Drone Damage Amplifier with a Shield Power Relay. What you're looking for is to make sure you can tank 1700 dps.

> I found the following tip in the EVE Wiki:
>
> Tip from ShadowNeo29: the last pocket is pretty easy, kill only the
> Gurista Distributor, bookmark the wreck and warp out. Come back 2 min
> after for loot/salvage.
>
> I tried to bookmark the room and warp back, but that didn't work and I
> ended up at the first acceleration gate again. What exactly is this
> tip trying to achieve, how does it work and what could I have done
> wrong?

ShadowNeo29 is attempting to blitz the complex. Killing the Gurista Distributor is the trigger for completing the complex. By bookmarking the wreck, warping out of the deadspace pocket and waiting 5 or so minutes, you are forcing the deadspace pocket to despawn so you do not need to kill any more NPC ships.

Why the deadspace pocket did not despawn for you can be one of the following:

1. You killed the wrong ship.
2. You need to wait a little bit longer (5 minutes should be good).
3. There was someone else in the complex.
4. Leaving any player items behind (Drones, Mobile Tractor Units and cans are common examples).